# Collections.sort with Comparator<String[]> compile error

Tags: java, comparator, anonymous-class

I am having problem with compilation that I don't understand and would appreciate some help.
Excerpt from the code, other methods are omitted for brevity:

```
public class TableBuilder {
  List<String[]> rows = new LinkedList<String[]>();

  public void sortByColumn(final int colIndex) {
    int maxIdx = 0;
    for (String[] s : rows) maxIdx = Math.max(maxIdx, s.length - 1);
    if (colIndex < 0 || colIndex >= maxIdx) return

    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
            return strings[colIndex].compareTo(otherStrings[colIndex]);
        }
    });
  }
```

}

Error that I receive is:

```
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
                Collections.sort(rows ,new Comparator<String[]>() {
                                ^
```

When I change method signature to `public int sortByColumn(final int colIndex)` then I am getting error:

```
incompatible types
found   : void
required: int
                Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
                                ^
```

Why this code doesn't compile and how is `return` in anonymous `Comparator` class related to `sortByColumn` signature? Is it possibly compiler bug or what do I do wrong? Using javac 1.6.0_45.

Comment: Typo: `if (colIndex < 0 || colIndex >= maxIdx) return`. Insert `;` to complete the instruction. Always double-check all your code, not just the line highlighted by the compiler.

Comment: And always use braces around your if/while/for blocks. Yet another bug that would have been easier to diagnose if you had used braces.

Comment: This is a typo, I believe this could be close.

Comment: Thanks BackSlash, indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to remove the `return` statement, so that the code compiles:

```
public class TableBuilder {
    List<String[]> rows = new LinkedList<String[]>();

    public void sortByColumn(final int colIndex) {
        int maxIdx = 0;
        for (String[] s : rows) maxIdx = Math.max(maxIdx, s.length - 1);
        if (colIndex < 0 || colIndex >= maxIdx) {
            Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
                    return strings[colIndex].compareTo(otherStrings[colIndex]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `Collections.sort` method will sort the `rows` collection as a mutable object. It does not return a sorted collection as a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Your Comparator is fine. The problem is that you're trying to `return` the result of `Comparator#sort`, which is a `void`. Just lose the `return` statement and you should be OK:

```
if (colIndex > 0 && colIndex <= maxIdx) {
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
            return strings[colIndex].compareTo(otherStrings[colIndex]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: seems to be a check to validate the `colIndex` value. So it should be return or else do the sort ;)

Answer (score 0):

That was typo as highlighted by BackSlash